# ZF2 - get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getAlbumTable

Tags: zend-framework2

I used the getAlbumTable in the title since the problem I'm facing is based on the Zend Album Tutorial, might be easier for others having a similar problem to find. All I've done is rename  Album to "Champrallies".

My error:

```
Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for getChampralliesTable
```

What I'm trying to do is execute a function from a second Model I've created. I can execute from the 'original' model no problem AlbumTable or in my case ChampionshipTable. I'm trying to get data from a second table, but within the same module. The second table is called "champ_rallies" and the Model files are Champrallies.php and ChampralliesTable.php.

Changing this part in my controller

```
'champRallies' => $this->getChampralliesTable()->fetchAll(),
```

to

```
'champRallies' => $this->getChampionshipTable()->fetchAll(),
```

means the error message disappears. So my first thought is that there is something wrong with namespaces, or module.php. (Forgive me, I'm fairly new at all this)

Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Championship;

use Championship\Model\Championship;
use Championship\Model\ChampionshipTable;
use Championship\Model\Champrallies;
use Championship\Model\ChampralliesTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Championship\Model\ChampionshipTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ChampionshipTableGateway');
                    $table = new ChampionshipTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'ChampionshipTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Championship());
                    return new TableGateway('championships', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
                'Championship\Model\ChampralliesTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ChampralliesTableGateway');
                    $table = new ChampralliesTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'ChampralliesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Champrallies());
                    return new TableGateway('champ_rallies', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

My second thought is that perhaps I'm not declaring the right namespace, or something similar.

ChampralliesTable.php

```
<?php

namespace Championship\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class ChampralliesTable
```

Champrallies.php

```
<?php

namespace Championship\Model;

class Champrallies
```

I fear I'm overlooking something failure but I haven't found any similar posts through google or on here, any help is appreciated!

edit: I had forgotten to add getChampralliesTable function to the controller itself,

```
public function getChampralliesTable()
{
This is Line 50 -> if (!$this->champralliesTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->champralliesTable = $sm->get('Championship\Model\ChampralliesTable');
    }
    return $this->champralliesTable;
}
```

But now I'm getting this,

```
Notice: Undefined property: Championship\Controller\ChampionshipController::$champralliesTable in /usr/home/phil/git/rallystats/module/Championship/src/Championship/Controller/ChampionshipController.php on line 50
```

Comment: Just add the property to your controller: protected $champralliesTable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had forgotten to add getChampralliesTable function to the controller itself,

```
public function getChampralliesTable()
{
This is Line 50 -> if (!$this->champralliesTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->champralliesTable = $sm->get('Championship\Model\ChampralliesTable');
    }
    return $this->champralliesTable;
}
```

But now I'm getting this,

```
Notice: Undefined property: Championship\Controller\ChampionshipController::$champralliesTable in /usr/home/phil/git/rallystats/module/Championship/src/Championship/Controller/ChampionshipController.php on line 50
```

Solving this was just a matter of adding

```
protected $champralliesTable;
```

to the top of my ChampionshipController.

edit: Doing the above solves my problem.